# how to data bind to dropdownlist when checkbox is checked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I  have a project that using dropdownlist  for choices.When check  checkbox1  dropdown automatically bind data from database using  table1 and when I check checkbox2 dropdown automatically binding data from database using table2.I do not want to use get data by using any button .How can I do that .Please help me.

here is code by using button:

```
public  void LokasyonDoldur()
    {
        birimBUS = new BirimBUSV1();
        List<BirimVO> birimVO = new List<BirimVO>();
        DrpChcs.Items.Clear();
        List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
        birimVO = birimBUS.LokasyonlariGetir();
        foreach (var item in birimVO)
        {
            items.Add(new ListItem(item.BirimAdi, item.ID.ToString()));
        }
        DrpChcs.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
    }
    public void BirimleriDoldur()
    {
        PoliklinikBUS poliklinikBUS = new PoliklinikBUS();
        List<PoliklinikVO> poliklinikVO = new List<PoliklinikVO>();
        DrpChcs.Items.Clear();
        List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
        poliklinikVO = poliklinikBUS.Poliklinikler();
        foreach (var item in poliklinikVO)
        {
            items.Add(new ListItem(item.PoliklinikAdi, item.ID.ToString()));
        }
        DrpChcs.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
    }
    protected void BtnLokasyon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChckLctn.Checked == true && ChckBrm.Checked==false)
        {
            LokasyonDoldur();
        }
        else if (ChckLctn.Checked == false && ChckBrm.Checked == true)
        {
            BirimleriDoldur();
        }
        else
        {

        }
        Button1.Visible = true;
        BtnLokasyon.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void DrpChcs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KirilimId = Int32.Parse(DrpChcs.SelectedValue);
        BPolikilinikID= KirilimId;
    }
```

but I do not want to use this one.

Comment: Do you have some code examples from what you have now?

Comment: I added some codes but I do not want use this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohh its another language. its hard to read. but what you basicly have to do is check which checkbox is checked in the page load and then load the dropdown based on what is loaded.

something like this. (I have typed it from my head so its not like copy-paste but you get the idea)

```
page_load
{
    if(checkbox1.checked)
    {
        dropdown.dataitems = items1;
        dropdown.databind();
        return;
    }

    if(checkbox2.checked)
    {
        dropdown.dataitems = items2;
        dropdown.databind();
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can call the Button1_click event from the Dropdown list selected index changed event like this

```
Button1_Click(Button1,new EventArgs());
```

and in this you can hide that button from the page and in code behind you are calling the same function

OR

You can refactor the code in a seperate function from the button click event and call that function in the selected index changed event.

Please let me knwo if  I misunderstood your question

Thanks